Is the set refered to by a symmetric group necessarily $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$?
A finite symmetric group consists of the set of all transformations of a set $X$, called permutations of the elements of $X$, and in which the law of composition is the binary composition of these transformations.
Is it necessary that $X$ be the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, or can the symmetric group of order $n$ apply to any finite set $X$ of cardinality $n$?
What about the notation $S_n$?
On Wikipedia, it is stated:

The symmetric group of degree $n$ is the symmetric group on the set $X=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$... If $X$ is the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ then the name may be abbreviated to $\mathrm {S} _{n}$...

Similarly, in Peter Szekeres's "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics" it is stated (p. 30):

The group of permutations of $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is called the symmetric group of order $n$, denoted $S_n$.

In Lang's "Algebra" (on page 30 in the revised 3rd edition I have), it is stated:

Let $S_n$ be the group of permutations of a set with $n$ elements. This set may be taken to be the set of integers $J_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

From Lang's definition, it sounds like $S_n$ can refer to any finite set $X=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ of cardinality $n$ and not necessarily the set of integers $1$ to $n$.
This makes more sense to me - I don't see why we would need to restrict it to the set of integers.

Yes, we can define the symmetric group of any set. For a set $X$, we usually denote $S_X$ to be the set of bijections $X \to X$, which is a group under composition. It works even if $X$ is infinite. When $X = {1, 2, \ldots, n}$, we use the shortcut notation $S_n$. Of course, if $|X|=n$, then $S_X$ and $S_n$ are isomorphic, so we often restrict our study to the symmetric groups $S_n$.

So what is the difference between ${1,2,\dots,n}$ and ${x_1,\dots,x_n}$? From my view, they are the same object.

Duplicate question. Please use site search.

@Andrew they are not.

well, i mean $x_1$can be a cat and not a quantity

@MartinBrandenburg Please link the duplicate question to confirm.

When $X$ has $n$ elements with group structure , we can "name" or "call" the $n$ elements like $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ , which are not necessarily Integers : vectors , matrices , rational numbers , irrational numbers , graphs , knots are all occurring various scenarios.
Then $x_{n_1} \times x_{n_2} = x_{n_3}$ , using the group operation.
We can eliminate complexity by just using or changing the "names" we use to "call" those elements to just $n_1,n_2,n_3$ to get ${n_1} \times {n_2} = {n_3}$ , using that group operation.
Hence we can always use $S_n$ without loss of information , even when $X$ was not $S_n$.
SUMMARY : (1) In general , $X$ need not be $S_n$ (2) While using $X=S_n$ , we make it less complex without loss of information.

OP is asking how to construct a symmetric group with a set $X$ which is not ${1,2,\ldots,n}$. OP doesn't assume a group structure on $X$.

The word "construct" occurs only in your comment , not in Query Post , @eti902 , while the title is clearly asking whether $X$ is necessarily $S_n$ always .... I am saying it is immaterial because we can always call/name/rename them like that.

Please avoid answering duplicate questions and instead help to find the corresponding duplicate. See also here.
